# Change current_user to another user from drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

Ok i have a back office app that i am building.. (Office USE ONLY)

in this app it will be nessassary to swap users occasionally and use app as user.

is there a way i can change the `current_user` to the user selected in a form on submit.

I am using Devise and rails 3

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) gem, it seems to be what you're looking for and last commit is from 2 months ago.